# Access Query with complex sorting requirements

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, subquery

I have to generate Q-Q plots from a continually expanding dataset. In order to do this I have to have two columns sorted independently of each other.

Like this:

Main table

```
F1 | F2
---+----
6  | 10
8  |  7
2  |  5
```

The final table should sort like this:

```
F1 | F2
---+----
2  |  5
6  |  7
8  | 10
```

I attempted to do this with two joined subqueries and a VBA function that added a row number to each subquery. It did not return any values, although each subquery works on its own.

This is the SQL query that I attempted to use:

```
SELECT 
    wautonumber([Au_org_gpt]) AS index_no, 
    ORG.Project, ORG.Au_org_gpt AS Au_org_gpt_QQ, 
    MTS.Au_mts_gpt AS Au_mts_gpt_QQ 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         wautonumber([Au_org_gpt]) AS index_no, 
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Project, MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Au_org_gpt
     FROM
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts
     ORDER BY 
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Au_org_gpt) AS ORG 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         wautonumber([Au_mts_gpt]) AS index_no, 
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Project, MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Au_mts_gpt
     FROM
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts
     ORDER BY 
         MCIPLD_geochem_mts.Au_mts_gpt)  AS MTS ON ORG.index_no = MTS.index_no;
```

Comment: Do this in VBA.  Don't do this in MS Access.

Comment: Post the wautonumber() code.

Comment: The wautonumber() code is:Function wAutoNumber(i) As Long
    If Now - lastcall > 4 / 60 / 60 / 24 Then
        lastcall = Now
        seqNumber = -1
    End If
    seqNumber = seqNumber + 1
    wAutoNumber = seqNumber
End Function

Comment: Probably won't make any difference at this point, but you should edit question with info like that, not throw it into a comment.

Comment: Use _Excel_ - built for this.

Comment: I will next time.  I'm neither a programmer or a SQL expert so this is kind of new to me.  The problem with Excel is that it is static and this is a dataset that grows every few weeks. I would prefer that the dataset be automatically updated by the query.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both fields have data in every record.

If both fields have unique number values, consider:

```
SELECT Query1.Seq, Query1.F1, Query2.F2
FROM
(SELECT DCount("*","Main","F2<=" & [F2]) AS Seq, Main.F2
    FROM Main ORDER BY Main.F2) AS Query2 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DCount("*","Main","F1<=" & [F1]) AS Seq, Main.F1
    FROM Main ORDER BY Main.F1) AS Query1 
ON Query2.Seq = Query1.Seq
ORDER BY Query1.Seq;
```

Another query approach requires two query objects:

Query1

```
SELECT "F1" AS Src, F1 AS Data FROM Main
UNION SELECT "F2", F2 FROM Main;
```

Query 2

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT DCount("*","Query1","Src='" & [Src] & "' AND Data<=" & [Data]) AS Seq
FROM Query1
GROUP BY DCount("*","Query1","Src='" & [Src] & "' AND Data<=" & [Data])
PIVOT Query1.Src;
```

Both solutions might perform slowly with large dataset.

Here is VBA approach. Build a table called MainSorted with 3 fields:

Seq - autonumber
F1 - number
F2 - number

```
Sub MainSort()
Dim rsSrc As Recordset, db As Database
Dim lngRow As Long
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "DELETE FROM MainSorted"
db.Execute "INSERT INTO MainSorted(F1) SELECT F1 FROM Main ORDER BY F1"
Set rsSrc = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT F2 FROM Main ORDER BY F2")
lngRow = DMin("Seq", "MainSorted")
While Not rsSrc.EOF
    db.Execute "UPDATE MainSorted SET F2=" & rsSrc!F2 & " WHERE Seq = " & lngRow
    rsSrc.MoveNext
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Or this version:

```
Sub MainSort()
Dim rsSrc1 As Recordset, rsSrc2 As Recordset, db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "DELETE FROM MainSorted"
Set rsSrc1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT F1 FROM Main ORDER BY F1")
Set rsSrc2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT F2 FROM Main ORDER BY F2")
While Not rsSrc1.EOF
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO MainSorted(F1,F2) VALUES(" & rsSrc1!F1 & "," & rsSrc2!F2 & ")"
    rsSrc1.MoveNext
    rsSrc2.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Considering @CPerkins comments:

```
Sub MainSort()
Dim rsSrc1 As Recordset, rsSrc2 As Recordset, rsDest As Recordset, db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "DELETE FROM MainSorted"
Set rsSrc1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT F1 FROM Main ORDER BY F1")
Set rsSrc2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT F2 FROM Main ORDER BY F2")
Set rsDest = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MainSorted")
While Not rsSrc1.EOF
    rsDest.AddNew
    rsDest!F1 = rsSrc1!F1
    rsDest!F2 = rsSrc2!F2
    rsDest.Update
    rsSrc1.MoveNext
    rsSrc2.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give this a try and otherwise see if I can sort it out in VBA as Gordon suggested.

Comment: This solution worked well, but as you indicates was very slow.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: It's better to call CurrentDb once and assign it to a local variable like `db As Database`, then reuse that variable.  CurrentDb recreates a new object each time it is called and is **especially inefficient inside a While loop**.

Comment: It's not worth writing my own solution since this contains plenty of great examples of what to do. But regarding either VBA version, it will likely be more efficient to open the MainSorted table (i.e. the destination table) as a DAO updatable recordset rather than executing individual update/insert SQL calls.